# objective c Translate block to selector

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

the following block will get called when menu clicked.

```
CCMenuItem* iconItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:icon 
                                          selectedSprite:icon2 
                                          block:^(id sender) {
    [self buttonClickedWithUnlocked:unlocked world:world];
}];
```

and i can pass parameter to the method inside the block.

but now i am translating obj-c to c++. thus block is not supported. i need to use selector like:

```
 CCMenuItem* iconItem = 
 CCMenuItemSprite::itemFromNormalSprite(icon, icon2, this,              
 menu_selector(SomeClass::buttonClickedWithUnlockedWorld(unlocked, w)));
```

but i am not able to pass in the parameter (not supported by selector)
so is there any other way to do it?

in case you don't use c++, the Obj-c version of selector is:

```
CCMenuItem* iconItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:icon 
                                          selectedSprite:icon2 
                                          target: self
                                          selector: @selector(buttonClickedWithUnlocked)
}];
```

but still, i can't pass in any parameter to the @selector either. 
any other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your obj-c version should be `selector: @selector(buttonClickedWithUnlocked::)` instead of `selector: @selector(buttonClickedWithUnlocked)` (Note the `::`). So for your C++ version you need to create something like `[target performSelector:selector withObject:obj1 withObject:obj2]`.

So in Obj-C it could look like this:

```
CCMenuItem* iconItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:icon 
                                      selectedSprite:icon2 
                                      target: self
                                      selector: @selector(buttonClickedWithUnlocked::)
                                      param1: [NSNumber numberWithInt:unlocked]
                                      param2: [NSNumber numberWithBool:w]
}];
```

and `buttonClickedWithUnlocked` must be defined to have two NSNumber parameters.

Comment: what about the method get passed in? could you provide the signature or code example? can i just pass in an integer and a bool?